# How do I suppress the sorting of my folder using $find command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder that contains items that have an ID of Guid. My script iterates this folder to submit child processes. I have found that the `find` command used to retrieve the contents of the folder into a collection is retrieving them in a sorted order. I need this to be in FIFO order. I want them in the order they were placed in the folder (which is a pseudo "queue"; the contents are jobs to be submitted to the process).

Here is my `find` command. What can I do?.

```
DIRECTORIES=$(find $queue_root -mindepth 1 -type d)
```

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) before writing more shell code.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel `find` does not sort anything. It just returns the files in a kernel implementation dependent order. If you want it sorted according to something, you have to do that yourself

Comment: `ls -lc` sort by ctime, if you have sure nothing changed the file, you can use it.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino : [please don't](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, ...typically, a filesystem (at the kernel level, out of `find`'s control!) will use a hashmap or tree data structure. As in many other languages, the order of a map is either arbitrary (depending on how values hash), or forced to be in sort order (if the tree uses names directly as keys in the tree).

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, BTW, re: `directories=$(...)` as a whole, see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) (re: the "obvious" array alternative), and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (re: doing it right).

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, ...all that said, if you're creating a directory structure to use as a queue, I'd suggest making the names part of the ordering. Prefix with `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.NNN`, and then you have a well-defined order that doesn't require the mtimes to be intact.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list returned by `find` this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

queue_root=.

# print the list of directories preceded by their timestamp
find "$queue_root" -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%A@ %f\n' |
  # sort the list by timestamps
  sort -n |
  # print only the directory names from the sorted list
  awk '{ print $2 }'
```

To deal with directory names with arbitrary characters like newline or other non-printable, the above script can be adapted like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

queue_root=.

# Handling directories with arbitrary characters

while IFS= read -r -d '' directory; do
  echo "$directory" # do stuff with directory
done < <(
# print the null delimited list of directories preceded by their timestamp
find "$queue_root" -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%A@ %f\0' |
  # sort the list by timestamps
  sort --numeric-sort --zero-terminated |
  # print only the directory names from the sorted list
  cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2- --zero-terminated
)
```

With a POSIX restricted shell, you would use `xargs` to distribute the directories like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

queue_root=.
# Handling directories with arbitrary characters

# print the null delimited list of directory preceded by their timestamp
find "$queue_root" -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%A@ %f\0' |
  # sort the list by timestamps
  sort --numeric-sort --zero-terminated |
  # print only the directory names from the sorted list
  cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2- --zero-terminated |
  # use xargs to provide the directory argument to command
  # from the null delimited list of directories
  xargs --null --max-args=1 echo # replace echo with command to do stuff with directory
```

Comment: The only caveat here is that it's only safe to delimit a list of directory names with literal newlines if you know there can't be a newline in your names! If one needs to deal safely with completely unknown/untrusted names, better to use a format string with `\0` instead of `\n`, and modify the downstream tools appropriately (`sort -z`, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added null-terminated list support